# How to use rsgislib python binds in windows environment

Tags: python, windows, digital-image-processing

I am right now would like to use *rsgislib* to create a simplify remote sensing image processing application based on python.
However I have no idea about how to use *rsgislib* in windows.

Perhaps someone would like to share about using *rsgislib* in windows or a substitute python library for *rsgislib*.

rsgislib: The Remote Sensing and GIS software library (RSGISLib) is a collection of tools for processing remote sensing and GIS datasets. The tools are accessed using Python bindings or an XML interface.
http://www.rsgislib.org/

Comment: What type of image processing are you doing?

Answer (score 3):

Binaries of RSGISLib are now available on Windows via conda-forge. To install:

1) Download miniconda from https://conda.io/miniconda.html and install

2) Within the conda terminal, install RSGISLib to a new environment using:

```
conda create -n rsgislib -c conda-forge rsgislib
```

3) Once installed activate the new environment using

```
activate rsgislib
```

RSGISLib has been developed and is primarily used on macOS and Linux so it is possible there are some Windows specific bugs.

Answer (score 2):

So far I know RSGISLIB uses GDAL/OGR's C library with Python binding, it's not Python in base. Almost all of today's geoprocessing and remote sensing applications use [GDAL and OGR](http://gdal.org/python/). In Windows you can either install GDAL and OGR utilities inside python, or use in CLI. You can even try [Orfeo-toolbox](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/). [GRASS](https://grass.osgeo.org/) has an extensive library for raster processing inside Python. Windows has a wonderful tool called [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) which can guide you to install many similar utilities along with their dependencies.

Also try these links

- [Recommended programming language for remote sensing?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85386/recommended-programming-language-for-remote-sensing) (has names of some software available for windows)
- [What is the best open source software package for Remote Sensing?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36736/what-is-the-best-open-source-software-package-for-remote-sensing)(just more names !)
- [Installing RSGISLib on Windows through a Virtual Machine](https://spectraldifferences.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/installing-rsgislib-on-windows-through-a-virtual-machine/)   ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run RSGISLib on Windows 10 using the Windows Bash shell. I have run the RSGISLib python tests successfully, but I have not tried anything else.

1. Install Windows Bash Shell - follow instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/commandline/wsl/install_guide).
2. Download and install [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) (linux 64bit).
3. Install the rsgislib packages:

   conda create -n rsgislib python=3.5

   conda install -c conda-forge gdal

   conda install -c conda-forge -c rios rsgislib
4. I also had to install libopenblas-base:

   sudo apt-get install libopenblas-base

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/openblas-base/

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/
5. Download and run the python tests from the [RSGISLib bitbucket page](https://bitbucket.org/petebunting/rsgislib), to see if it has worked.